# No Pages getting crawled in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following spider in Scrapy which is to be used to crawl and save web pages from eBay.com, for ray-ban sunglasses

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class EbaySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ebay'
    allowed_domains = ['ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.ebay.com',
        'http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1312.R1.TR11.TRC2.A0.H0.Xray.TRS1&_nkw=ray+ban+sunglasses&_sacat=0'
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'itm/.*ray.*ban.*sunglassses']), follow='true', callback='parse_item')
    ]    

    def parse_item(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

and this is the output i get:

```
INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-09-03 12:50:11 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-03 12:50:11 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-09-03 12:50:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-09-03 12:50:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 

http://www.ebay.com> (referer: None)
    2015-09-03 12:50:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2015-09-03 12:50:12 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 210,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 25707,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 19, 50, 12, 755020),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 19, 50, 11, 809426)}
2015-09-03 12:50:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Can somebody point out what is wrong? I am a noob to scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing on the page matches the regular expressions in the string `r'itm/.*ray.*ban.*sunglassses'`.  You can test this by launching a shell pointed at your start_url, and doing the following:

```
>>> from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor
>>> LinkExtractor(allow=[r'itm/.*ray.*ban.*sunglassses']).extract_links(response)
[]
```

First, to get it out of the way (it's the big culprit), is the typo in "Sunglasses" (you have three 's').

Second, regular expressions are case sensitive by default, so `r'ray.*ban'` won't match a link containing "Ray-ban" or "Ray Ban".  To correct this, pre-compile your regular expression with the `IGNORECASE` flag, and pass that to your link extractor.

```
import re
...
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[re.compile(r'itm/.*ray.*ban.*sunglasses', re.IGNORECASE)]), 
         follow='true', callback='parse_item')
]
```